# Passing Morris Chart data by Viewmodel property with MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, morris.js

I am building a Morris Chart based on a database data and I pass to the View using the Viewmodel:

Razor code:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SurveyLastDaysChartData)
```

HTML code:

```
<input id="SurveyLastDaysChartData" name="SurveyLastDaysChartData" type="hidden" value="[{"Date":"2016-07-18","Average":0},{"Date":"2016-07-17","Average":0},{"Date":"2016-07-16","Average":0},{"Date":"2016-07-15","Average":4.125},{"Date":"2016-07-14","Average":0},{"Date":"2016-07-13","Average":0},{"Date":"2016-07-12","Average":0}]">
```

The problem is that the Javascript side can't read the data because it's in string format.

```
var _surveyLastDaysChartId = "dsb-survey-last-days-chart";
var _surveyLastDaysChartData = $("#SurveyLastDaysChartData");

Morris.Line({
        // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
        element: _surveyLastDaysChartId,
        // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on the chart.
        data: _surveyLastDaysChartData.val(),
        // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
        xkey: 'Date',
        // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
        ykeys: ['Average'],
        // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the chart.
        labels: ['Value']
    });
```

I would like to keep the chart data in the Viewmodel and avoid Javascript in the View, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, serialize the property and set to a javascript variable. This will be JSON.

```
<script>
var chartData = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
                                        .SerializeObject(Model.SurveyLastDaysChartData));
</script>
```

Now you can use the `chartData` variable in your javascript code.

Comment: In this case, you need to pass the model data. So you need to have this line in your razor view (as it is using C# code)

Comment: Yes. In this usecase, It is fine to have it.

Comment: Onde last thing, is it better to Serialize on the Controller or like your answer?  model.SurveyLastDaysChartData = jsonSerializer.Serialize(chartData);

Comment: You want that in a client side javascript variable. Rite  ? Then you should do it in your razor view.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
data : @(Html.Raw(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(Model.ListOfYouNeed)))
```

Comment: Hi thanks! Sorry but I have check Shyju's answer has correct because he has responded first.